# Ubuntu 18.04 sever without network after move SSD from PC1 to PC2

Tags: 18.04, server, ssd

I tested on Ubuntu 18.04 desktop it is OK. But I tested Ubuntu 18.04 server or 20.04 server , I move SSD from PC1 to PC2 then PC2 without network, without too from Hyper-V to PC1 (by dd & balena etcher)
I wanna distribution to many PC without monitor (coin mining), It need auto command in bash file to fix this error. Help me, please! I'm not found in similar questions.

**PS:**

cmd **ip a** result:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:79:59:6a:6f:88 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

cmd **ip r** result: empty string ('')

cmd **cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml** result:

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

Comment: From PC2 without network, please run the terminal commands: `ip a` and also: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Next, edit your question to show the result. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I updated new cmd result

Answer (score 0):

Please notice that the relevant ethernet interface is enp3s0; however, the netplan file refers to eth0. Please edit your netplan yaml file to replace eth0 with enp3s0. Follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

Is there any improvement?

Comment: Thankyou very much!

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou chili555.
I success fix this error, below is file bash auto fix:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

    eth0=`ip a | grep "state DOWN" | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | cut -d ':' -f 1`
    if [[ ! -z "$eth0" ]] ; then
        echo "Internet isn't present"

        filelist=(/etc/netplan/*.yaml)

        for ((i0=0; i0 < ${#filelist[@]}; i0++)); do
            #echo changing file: ${filelist[$i0]}
            eth1=`cat ${filelist[$i0]} | grep '    ' | cut -d ' ' -f 5 | cut -d ':' -f 1`
            #echo eth1 = $eth1, eth0 = $eth0
            sed -i "s/$eth1/$eth0/g" ${filelist[$i0]}
        done
        sudo netplan generate
        sudo netplan apply
    else
        echo "Internet is present"
    fi
```